# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new to Retrofit. Below is my code to get vendor list

Sample JSON response is json array & not json object

```
[
{
"Key" : "1",
"Value" : "xyz"
},
{
"Key" : "2",
"Value" : "abc"
}
]
```

Below is my code

```
private void callToRetrofit() {
    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient()
            .create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<List<SD_Checklist_Supplier_Model>> call = apiInterface.getVendors();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SD_Checklist_Supplier_Model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<SD_Checklist_Supplier_Model>> call, Response<List<SD_Checklist_Supplier_Model>> response) {
            Log.v("onResponse", " : ok" +  response == null ? " null" : "okkkk" + response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<SD_Checklist_Supplier_Model>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("onFailure", " : " + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Model class

```
public class SD_Checklist_Supplier_Model {

    @SerializedName("Key")
    private String supplierID;
    @SerializedName("Value")
    private String supplierName;
    private boolean isSupplierSelected;

    public String getSupplierID() {
        return supplierID;
    }

    public void setSupplierID(String supplierID) {
        this.supplierID = supplierID;
    }

    public String getSupplierName() {
        return supplierName;
    }

    public void setSupplierName(String supplierName) {
        this.supplierName = supplierName;
    }

    public boolean isSupplierSelected() {
        return isSupplierSelected;
    }

    public void setSupplierSelected(boolean supplierSelected) {
        isSupplierSelected = supplierSelected;
    }
}
```

Currently, I am getting

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Please help me.

Comment: Check your API in POSTMAN . It must be coming in an object not in array. As error mentions.

Comment: As I already mentioned. It is json array not standard json object inside it

Comment: will you share the API url ?

Comment: I can't due to privacy policy.

Answer (score 0):

Your Response of API call is a list and you are not assigning to a list.

Change your code

```
 Call<SD_Checklist_Supplier_Model> call = apiInterface.getVendors();
```

as

```
 Call<List<SD_Checklist_Supplier_Model>> call = apiInterface.getVendors();
```

Comment: I tried this but after doing this api call is not performing

Comment: Can you show your  'SD_Checklist_Supplier_Model' class

Comment: No error. It is not calling api I guess. Because it jumps out when I set debugger

Comment: Neither calling onResponse() nor onFailure()

Comment: Have you replaced all 'SD_Checklist_Supplier_Model' with list in the api call and response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152879/discussion-between-vvb-and-sibin-davis).